# Laravel how to create a column with timestamp which update the time each time if i make any changes to other columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Laravel

How to create a column with timestamp which update the time each time if i make any changes to other columns

Comment: every migration you create it has `timestamp` that contain `created_at` and `updated_at` that it is updated every time you make change

Comment: actually there are two columns as u told created_at and updated_at, but it does not working even if i make any changes to other columns

Comment: check out my answer it may help you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add additional column aside from the already given ones for each migration, the `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamps then when you create a `timestamp` column in your database, if you don't specify it manually to be `nullable()` then by default it will add the constraint `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

So in your migration just add the column like this:

```
$table->timestamp('your_column_name');
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution to your problem

for example, if you want to update your user after some changes

```
$user->touch()
```

> It should be an instance of your model